# How to refactor a top-level class or interface to an inner one in Eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, refactoring

I have an interface that I want to move inside another type.  Is there any way to get Eclipse to help me make that change?  The same change could also be applied to a class to move it inside another.

Basically, I'm looking for the reverse of *Convert Member Type to Top Level*. I hoped it would be Move, but that only offers packages as targets.

Comment: I'm not going to try to talk you out of it. I am going to say that if the most popular [citation needed] Java IDE in the world doesn't have it for the same reason Java doesn't allow `goto`: you probably shouldn't do it. :-)

Comment: the **best** java IDE had this feature on day 1, and eclipse have had a decade to copy from the best.

Comment: @corsiKa According to http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/nested.html, there are some benefits of using inner classes, so why avoid them?

Comment: @thSoft I'm not saying there aren't benefits to using inner classes. I'm saying it's probably a bad idea to take one that's separated and integrate it. Particularly an interface: how likely is it that the interface is only useful inside that class? That's not very interface-y.

Comment: @corsiKa I used to find myself often declaring e.g. a separate Foo class along with a FooType enum. I think this is a typical use case where this kind of refactoring would be useful. :)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

1. Cut the Interface and paste it into the class where you want to embed it
2. Add the `static` keyword if the inner class should be reachable without an instance of the outer class.
3. In the Package Explorer, select your project and right click > source > organize imports

I think this will get most, if not all, of the compilation errors.

Comment: It does not fix any other classes that depend on the interface however

Comment: Note that for a top-level class, you should add `static` to its modifiers after pasting it as a nested class, in order for it to be semantically equivalent.

Comment: Also of note at this time, Eclipse does not provide built in support. See https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=37572